# TV show or film where dwarf hides in hay before being thrown in fire

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This was on TV and can't have been past 2004 - it might have been the '90s.

This was live-action.

Flipping channels, I saw something [I think it was a pigman?] looking for dwarves hiding in a pile of hay in a barn or perhaps a prison.  He finds one, who yells to be let go, before he throws him into the fire.

I think there was a boy or man in a red jacket - probably the main character - also hiding while watching this happen.  I think maybe the pigman transformed into something else, perhaps a big demon?  Maybe after being pushed into the fire himself?

Sorry I don't have more details.  This is the only part of the show or movie I caught at the time.

Comment: This partially relates to elements from the [Time Bandits](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=time+bandits&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images) film [from 1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bandits) by Terry Gilliam but not quite.

Comment: Was it subtitled or dubbed? The main character in red and the pigman make me think of the Japanese show Monkey (1978), which was dubbed into English in the 80s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_(TV_series)

Comment: Hmm I don't believe it was as old as the 70s.  This was on cable in the US or Canada in the late 90s - early 00s.  It was in English or at least dubbed.

Comment: I thought this may be from one of the Deathstalker films; time period, pigman, hero in red top (in one film at least). But after skipping through them, that doesn't appear to be one of the scenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be remembering the first "kitchen" scene from the 1985 movie, [Legend](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089469).

At around 0h 45m into the theatrical release, Jack (the human hero) and a small cohort of faeries (two of which are dwarves) have fallen into prison cells in Darkness' kitchen. They are greeted by an armored former foe in an adjacent cell, who reveals himself to also be a dwarf, Blunder. He admonishes the heroes to keep quiet or they all (himself included) will be "barbecue".

Just then, the cells are approached by a prison guard (referred to as a Demon Cook on the IMDB credits page) who is wearing a sort of leather mask that gives him an appearance similar to a pig-man. Jack and the faerie folk all hastily hide beneath piles of straw on the floor of their cells. The prison guard sniffs around outside the cells, then enters the cell in which Blunder is hiding. The prison guard yanks him out from beneath the straw and carries him toward the roaring cookfires. Blunder screams to be let go, while the others look on from behind the bars of their own cell, unable to help.

I cannot account for your memory of a red jacket other than the entire scene is cast in reds and yellows due to being lit by the huge fires. Jack is wearing highly polished gold scale armor, which reflects this light.

In a later scene (starting around 1h 06m of the theatrical release) the heroes battle both prison guards (the pig-man-like one and another who wears a pointy hood). Eventually, the dwarves are able to tip one of the boiling cauldrons off the fire and scald the guards/cooks to death, surrounded by billowing steam. This is similar to your description of the pig-man being thrown into the fire, though he doesn't transform into anything different.

It might be worth mentioning that Legend also has a character that is indeed a pig-man, named Pox, though he is not in either of the kitchen scenes mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you!  I just rented this to confirm!  This scene has been in my head for years but I'd always assumed it was a tv show.  Legend would come up in my search but the synopsis never seemed to fit the bill.